# Почему при таком срезе выводится последний элемент?

Tags: python

```
users_messages = ['I love my dog', 'I want to run', 'I want a hotdog', 'I want to sleep']
print(users_messages[:2:-1])
```

Comment: язык программирования Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/4827341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас есть элементы с индексами 0, 1, 2, 3. Шаг -1 означает проход с конца. Вот Вы и идёте с конца до второго элемента (правая граница не включается). А так как нет индексов больше 3, то и выводится только один последний элемент. Добавьте в конец списка ещё элемент, тогда напечатается два:)